# Virtual Neural Network in Python

Tags: python

I just wrote up a simple neural network in python as I have been studying them recently. I am using backpropogation. The activation function is a sigmoid. The inputs and weights generate randomly and the ideal output is 0. I am new to python so the code is written very inefficiently, but it is readable. When I run the code, the output is always zero and I can't seem to find why. Also, I didn't use a module.

```
from random import uniform
input_one_input_value = 1
input_two_input_value = 0
bias_value = 1

#use global to globalize function-based variables
#use lists to store data in future
def hidden_One():
    global weighted_sum_hidden_one
    weighted_sum_hidden_one = (input_one_input_value * weights[0]) + (input_two_input_value * weights[1]) + (bias_value * weights[2])
    hidden_one_output = activation(weighted_sum_hidden_one)
    return hidden_one_output

def hidden_Two():
    global weighted_sum_hidden_two
    weighted_sum_hidden_two = (input_one_input_value * weights[3]) + (input_two_input_value * weights[4]) + (bias_value * weights[5])
    hidden_two_output = activation(weighted_sum_hidden_two)
    return hidden_two_output

def output_One():
    weighted_sum = (hidden_One() * weights[6]) + (hidden_Two() * weights[7]) + (bias_value * weights[8])
    return activation(weighted_sum)

def activation(x):
    sigmoid_value = 1 / (1+(2.71828 ** x))
    return sigmoid_value

def calculate_gradient():
    E = ideal_output - actual_output
    output_delta = -E * activation(weights[6] + weights[7] + weights[8])
    h1_delta = activation(weighted_sum_hidden_one) * weights[6] * output_delta
    h2_delta = activation(weighted_sum_hidden_two) * weights[7] * output_delta  
    b2_delta = activation(bias_value) * weights[8] * output_delta
    i1_delta = activation(input_one_input_value) * ((weights[0] * h1_delta) + (weights[3] * h2_delta))
    i2_delta = activation(input_one_input_value) * ((weights[1] * h1_delta) + (weights[4] * h2_delta))
    b1_delta = activation(bias_value) * ((weights[2] * h1_delta) + (weights[5] * h2_delta))
    global w1_gradient
    global w2_gradient
    global w3_gradient
    global w4_gradient
    global w5_gradient
    global w6_gradient
    global w7_gradient
    global w8_gradient
    global w9_gradient
    w1_gradient = input_one_input_value * h1_delta
    w2_gradient = input_two_input_value * h1_delta
    w3_gradient = bias_value * h1_delta
    w4_gradient = input_one_input_value * h2_delta
    w5_gradient = input_two_input_value * h2_delta
    w6_gradient = bias_value * h2_delta
    w7_gradient = hidden_One() * output_delta
    w8_gradient = hidden_Two() * output_delta
    w9_gradient = bias_value * output_delta


def backpropogation():
    E = .7 #learning rate
    a = .3 #momentum to prevent settling for local minima
    global weightchanges_previous
    global weight_change
    weightchanges_previous = []
    weight_change = []
    if len(weightchanges_previous) == 0:
        weight_change.append((E * w1_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w2_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w3_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w4_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w5_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w6_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w7_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w8_gradient))
        weight_change.append((E * w9_gradient))
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[0])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[1])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[2])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[3])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[4])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[5])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[6])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[7])
        weightchanges_previous.append(weight_change[8])

    elif len(weightchanges_previous) != 0:
        weight_change[0] = (E * w1_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[0])
        weight_change[1] = (E * w2_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[1])
        weight_change[2] = (E * w3_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[2])
        weight_change[3] = (E * w4_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[3])
        weight_change[4] = (E * w5_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[4])
        weight_change[5] = (E * w6_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[5])
        weight_change[6] = (E * w7_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[6])
        weight_change[7] = (E * w8_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[7])
        weight_change[8] = (E * w9_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[8])
        while len(weightchanges_previous) > 0 : weightchanges_previous.pop()
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w1_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[0]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w2_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[1]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w3_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[2]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w4_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[3]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w5_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[4]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w6_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[5]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w7_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[6]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w8_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[7]))
        weightchanges_previous.append((E * w9_gradient) + (a * weightchanges_previous[8]))

def edit_weights():
    weights[0] += weight_change[0]
    weights[1] += weight_change[1]
    weights[2] += weight_change[2]
    weights[3] += weight_change[3]
    weights[4] += weight_change[4]
    weights[5] += weight_change[5]
    weights[6] += weight_change[6]
    weights[7] += weight_change[7]
    weights[8] += weight_change[8]
    while len(weight_change) > 0 : weight_change.pop()

weights = []
x = 0
while x <=8:
    weights.append(uniform(-10, 10))
    x += 1

ideal_output = 0
actual_output = output_One()
print "Output %d" % output_One()

x = 0
while x <= 10:
    output_One()
    calculate_gradient()
    backpropogation()
    edit_weights()
    print "Output %d" % output_One()
    print "----------------------"
    actual_output = output_One()
    x += 1

print "FINAL WEIGHTS:"
print weights[0]
print weights[1]
print weights[2]
print weights[3]
print weights[4]
print weights[5]
print weights[6]
print weights[7]
print weights[8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the output line:

```
print "Output %d" % output_One()
```

You're using `%d` which prints integer values so it rounds float values down to the nearest integer (integer conversion). Use `%f` instead and you should get the floating point numbers correctly.

Comment: @user2127869 Did this answer your question? If so, please mark it as answered so it's not dangling around as unanswered.

Comment: @user2127869: Great! The next step is to accept this answer. How this is done is described at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. In short: Click the check box below the reputation counter of the answer you want to accept.